# Recycler View with heterogenous rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to create recycler view with heterogenous rows.
Some rows will have imageview, some will have 5 textviews, some will have edit texts, some will have nested recycler views etc.
There is no pattern. How to do this?

What I researched and found :-
AirBnb Epoxy.

Please give some suggestion on how to proceed further with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like:
`public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecycleViewHolder>` then you must override a method named `onCreateViewHolder`. There are 2 arguments in this method ... one is the `ViewGroup parent` and the other one is `int viewType`.
You can change the whole row by checking `viewType` before creating new `Holder`.
For example:

```
if(viewType == 0){
        return new MyViewHolder(context,layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view_holder,null,false));

    } else {
        return new My2ViewHolder(context,layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_2_view_holder,null,false));
    }
```

Just don't forget that each ViewHolder must extend `CustomRecycleViewHolder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own ViewTypes as suggested. But I would suggest Epoxy is a good solution if you have multiple heterogeneous rows. Epoxy is very flexible and provides a lot of functions to build a heterogeneous RecyclerView out of the box. I have used it in multiple large-scale apps and it works really fine.
Instead of creating and keeping track of a lot of ViewHolders, you could just simply create models and use them like

```
headerModel
          .title("My Photos")
          .description("My album description!")
          .addTo(this);

new PhotoModel()
           .id(photo.id())
           .url(photo.url())
           .addTo(this);
```